# facing error during installation

Tags: magento-1.9

http://localhost/magento123/
Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://)

Answer (score 0):

open firegub or inspect element and just remove validation class on that input field. it works fine.

[image]

Comment: will u plz share a screen shot...??

Comment: inspect element of chrome?

Comment: Try it with URL like this : http://127.0.0.1/magento123/

Comment: i update my answer just check

Comment: thank u so much..when i've tried http://127.0.0.1/magento123/ then the error comes Database connection error

Comment: you enter wrong database name thats why this error occured

Comment: ya check that one.

Comment: i simply create a database,,not check privileges...is it ok? i mean to say should i add user name password,,like we do in wordpress after creating database?

Comment: you add root as username and password blank and add databse name

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the Base URL with this :

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento123/
```

Comment: tried...now the error comes ( Database connection error. )

Comment: make sure u specify correct username & pwd of the database

Answer (score 0):

At the installetion time you have  checkbox `skip base url validation` check on that checkbox and you will not see this error .

Hope this will help you

Comment: i've tried this,,but its still not working,,and i have been stucked here

Comment: manually write url at there

Comment: localhost/magento123/index.php/install/wizard/config/

Comment: `HTTP://localhost/magento123/index.php/install/wizard/config/` correct your url like this

Comment: corrected,,but its showing in the url bar like this  
localhost/magento123/index.php/install/wizard/config/

Comment: i simply create a database,,not check privileges...is it ok?

Comment: i mean to say should i add user name password,,like we do in wordpress after creating database?

Comment: you add root as username and password blank and add databse name